# Can't write results in a csv file slightly differently

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've created a script to parse the title and link of different posts from a webpage and write the same in a csv file. The script is doing fine. The output I'm having in that csv file contains `title` in column A and `link` in column B. However, what I like to do is write them slightly differently, as in `title` in row 1 and `link` in row 2 and so on.

To be clearer:

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOYA8.jpg) is my current output

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrwAD.jpg) is how I wish to achieve.

I've tried with:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

base = "https://stackoverflow.com"
url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"

res = requests.get(url,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
with open('stackoverflow.csv','w',newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['title','link'])
    for items in soup.select(".summary"):
        title = items.select_one(".question-hyperlink").get_text(strip=True)
        link = urljoin(base,items.select_one(".question-hyperlink").get("href"))
        writer.writerow([title,link])
```

How can I achieve the second output shown in the image above?

Comment: Why would you do that.. that doesnt even make sense.. But if you really want , you should have two writerow calls: writer.writerow(['title', title]), writer.writerow(['link', link]).. the writerow outside the forloop should be removed..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
writer.writerow([title,link])
```

with

```
writer.writerow(['title',title])
writer.writerow(['link',link])
```